# image and padding responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive, padding

can someone help to fix when i do responsive page the padding on image change from this
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92tkr.png)

to this
[responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtyY6.png)

```
.service-item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  }
```

how to fix that so there is no padding between those images in card

Comment: Do you want to add the border as shown in the images or do you want to remove the border? What do you mean by _when i do responsive page_? Some HTML would be useful to understand the problem.

Comment: The padding is not in the CSS of the image, it should be in the container. Can you show some more CSS rules and if possible html as well? This issue can easily be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="service-item">
    <img src="92tkr.png" />
  </div>
  <style>
    .service-item {
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
      padding: 20px 0; /* set padding top buttom */
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .service-item img {
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: block;
      width: 70%; /* set image width */
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where did you get this html? Are you the questioner?

Comment: I'm not the questioner.
It's just a sample solution (with html, css), based on the image from the questioner.
Without the exact specification it is impossible to offer a solution.